Is there something special about mail.domainXXX.com?
I have been trying to improve an already working DNS configuration for email delivery and found that for some reason I don't understand I need to have a mail.domainxxx.com A entry for my MX configuration to work, even if I don't make any reference to mail.domainxxx.com anywhere.

I was trying to remove the mail.domainxxx.com and leave only entries for domainxxx.com, but for some reason that specific mail.domainxxx.com A entry was needed (an of course corresponding MX entries).
Is there something documented in any RFC or similar specification document that I don't know about.
Update: Another clue for the error, when I use an AWS SES SMTP server I get the following delivery error

Reporting-MTA: dns; axx-xx.smtp-out.amazonses.com
Action: failed Final-Recipient: rfc822; raul.lapeira@domainxxx.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in
840 minutes.<421 4.4.1 Failed to establish connection> Status: 4.4.7


So what's in there? What exactly did you try and how did it fail?

What MX records do you have? And how many systems or servers are involved in mail delivery? Most importantly, where do you see the problem occuring – does your MX server reject the messages, or do the logs show no incoming delivery attempts at all?

No incoming activity at all. I can POP into the server but I get no emails because they are never delivered to the server. Only when I configure mail.domainxxx.com A and MX entries It works

You need to tell us the full configuration, because the question makes no sense as it stands. There's no magic hostnames when it comes to e-mail.

so basically there is nothing special about mail.domain.com or so? it must be something else?

Nothing special, and by the way, the question as it stands now was already asked and answered here. // @vidarlo suggested below that you finally tell us what domain you're using. We'll be able to verify what we can. You don't know what's important and what's not (else you weren't be asking), so just tell us everything and we'll filter out ourselves.

@NikitaKipriyanov the config is now working, rather not share... I will accept Lasse answer and assume my problem is something else

We can guess it's consultoriajava.com, which matches more or less with what you've posted and have in your profile. It turns out your MX probably has wrong hostname, and additionally doesn't reply beyond the initial 220 it sends. It ignores further input.

eheheh, its artifactconsulting.com, but as I said now it is with the working configuration so it could be dificult to pinpoint the route cause... I don't remember in the router having to configure anything about mail.domainxxx.com

As I understand the question you ask if why you need to have both a A record and a MX record in order to make emails work?
Well it can all be traced back to RFC974.
Assuming you have the domain example.com.
MX record tells which server will receive mails for @domain.com.
It may be a host with a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) belonging to the same domain ... or something completely different.
Assuming the MX is pointing towards the FQDN mail.example.com, then it is important that there exist an A record for that server if it is reachable over IPv4 and/or an AAAA record if it is reachable over IPv6.
If you do not declare an A or AAAA record, then how would the Internet know how to send emails for your domain? :-)
Update
Looking at you MX records you have:
| @.domainxxx.com | domainxxx.com |

It look a bit weird to me and I believe it is unnessesary.
The second line:
| mail.domainxxx.com | domainxxx.com |


This tell that any mails for domainxxx.com is handled by the host mail.domainxxx.com.
The next thing that happens is that senders mailserver will lookup the ip adress for your mailserver which is done by looking up the A record.
That is why you need to have an A record for mail.domainxxx.com.
Without the A record then the Internet will not know where your server is located.
Does it make sence now?

My point is that with domainxxx.com following the configuration you say, the email server does not receive emails, at all. I need to configure mail.domainxxx.com for it to work

Huh? If DNS settings are correct, then my next bet was to check if you have allowed traffic to the server on port 25 in the firewall although I know some ISP specifies you have to add a backup MX record that is pointing to your ISP mailserver. That is because the ISP block traffic to port 25 on your public ip address by default, unless is routed via your ISPs server.

I tried everything but as I say for some reason is the "mail.domainxxx.com" that makes the difference, ports seems to be ok. I am putting some screenshots and bounting this

Tell us the domain so we can have a look at things. There's no reason to redact such things, and it hampers answers.

You begin by testing your mailserver against internet.nl. If they can contact your mail server, then DNS settings are correct for inbound mails.

Answering to your update: the point is: If I dont configure ANYTHING at all about mail.domainxxx.com why emails go there, it is like I put MX and A with artifactconsulting and it does not work... or at least this is my experience on email servers and DNS with this case

Need to wait 5 hours for the bounty
